# SQL 2008 SQL Server Agents Jobs, how to populate email for Notifications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I am trying to add my email address to notifications for SQL Server Agent Job when it fails..

So I go SQL Server agent, open up the jobs, right click on the job and select properties and then notifications. I can check email there and have to select email address from a dropdown but the dropdown is blank and can't edit it..

Any Ideas

Comment: While this question is completely inappropriate here (because it is not a programming question), I couldn't do anything else than upvote it (and the accepted answer) because I had exactly the same problem, wasting an hour with it, and this was the first link in the Google search results.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to first create an operator for the SQL Agent to use. Under the SQL Server Agent folder, right click on the Operators folder and select "New Operator..." Supply a name for the operator and an email address. You'll then select this operator by the name you chose in the Notifications drop down for the job.

[image]